# Android and setContentView?

Tags: android

I have one activity, off this I have two classes.

When my app starts I setContentView to a layout that is in one of my classes.

Now inside this layout there is a button which needs to setContentView to the layout that is in my other class.

How can I change the content view? How can my subclass send a message back to my main class to tell it to change the setContentView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"off this I have two classes" are they subclasses to your activity, inner classes? Your problem is not really apparent to me.

The way I would do that is have two XML layouts and two activities: `layout1` and `layout2`, `Activity1` and `Activity2`.

You call `setContent(R.layout.layout1)` normally in your `onCreate` method in `Activity1`, and you add the following code in your button onClick method:

```
finish(); // to close current activity
startActivity(this, Activity2.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create another `Activity` which uses the second layout, and make that button launch that activity, like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: The method startActivity(Intent) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments (Context, Class<SettingsActivity>)